# C++ Multithreading - Output of the Code

Tags: c++, multithreading

"In the program, there are three threads and they run according to the 
following schedule order. What is the console output?"

Schedule Order - Thread Handle

- 1 h_thread1
- 2 h_thread3
- 3 h_thread3
- 4 h_thread1
- 5 h_thread1
- 6 h_thread2
- 7 h_thread2
- 8 h_thread3
- 9 h_thread3
- 10 h_thread2

Output of the code is: 
Player 1 eating : 0
Player 3 eating : 0
Player 2 eating : 0

I don't get it. I don't understand the process as a whole. Why "Player 1 eating : 0" showed in first line and "Player 3 eating : 0" in second? What is the logic behind this? Could you please explain the process.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
HANDLE forkMutexes[3]; 
DWORD WINAPI Player1(void* param){ 
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++){ //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 WaitForSingleObject(forkMutexes[2],INFINITE); //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 WaitForSingleObject(forkMutexes[0],INFINITE); //Computation Time : 1 Second
 cout << "Player 1 eating : " << i << endl; //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 ReleaseMutex(forkMutexes[2]); //Computation Time : 1 Second
 ReleaseMutex(forkMutexes[0]); //Computation Time : 1 Second
 } 
return 0; 
} 
DWORD WINAPI Player2(void* param){ 
for(int i =0; i < 4; i++){ //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 WaitForSingleObject(forkMutexes[0],INFINITE); //Computation Time : 1 Second
 WaitForSingleObject(forkMutexes[1],INFINITE); //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 cout << "Player 2 eating : " << i << endl; //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 ReleaseMutex(forkMutexes[0]); //Computation Time : 1 Second
 ReleaseMutex(forkMutexes[1]); //Computation Time : 1 Second
 } 
return 0; 
} 
DWORD WINAPI Player3(void* param){ 
for(int i =0; i < 1; i++){ //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 WaitForSingleObject(forkMutexes[1],INFINITE); //Computation Time : 1 Second
 WaitForSingleObject(forkMutexes[2],INFINITE); //Computation Time : 1 Second
 cout << "Player 3 eating : " << i << endl; //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 ReleaseMutex(forkMutexes[1]); //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 ReleaseMutex(forkMutexes[2]); //Computation Time : 2 Seconds
 } 
return 0; 
} 
int main() 
{ 
 HANDLE h_thread1, h_thread2,h_thread3; 
int i_threadID1, i_threadID2, i_threadID3; 
for(int i =0; i <3 ; i++) 
 forkMutexes[i] = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL); 
 h_thread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Player1, NULL, 
 0, (LPDWORD)&i_threadID1); 
 h_thread2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Player2, NULL, 
 0, (LPDWORD)&i_threadID2); 
 h_thread3 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Player3, NULL, 
 0, (LPDWORD)&i_threadID3); 
 WaitForSingleObject(h_thread1,INFINITE); 
 WaitForSingleObject(h_thread2,INFINITE); 
 WaitForSingleObject(h_thread3,INFINITE); 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Ar you asking why asynchronous (= out-of-order) execution happens out of order?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic multithreading problem, dining philosophers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem

`Player1`, `Player2` and `Player3` run in separate threads, created by `CreateThread`. Scheduling of threads are up to the OS, they run concurrently, the exact execution order is basically undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As you create thread1 first, player 1 is the first line. 
when Player1 is running, Player 2 is waiting for forkMutex0
and player 3 is waiting for forkMutex2, as forkMutex1 was not locked
as player1 release the forkMutex2 earlier than forkMutex0
player 3 will print earlier than player 2